# Methodology advice re: change sets

Tags: change-set

Still fairly new to Salesforce, and can see there are changes I’ve made in the sandbox that I won’t be able to transfer over to production(sharing settings,  standard object field-level security/accessibility, etc) via a change set.

I’m wondering if someone wouldn’t mind sharing their methodology as to how they work with sandbox change sets, mostly on how you ensure you’re bringing over all changes. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Refer (Application Lifecycle Management) https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/alm_deployment

Comment: Thanks - won't let me +1 because not enough rep points, but that's a great resource I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really use change sets, because the interface Salesforce provides for building them is, frankly, terrible. Instead, I use the [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm). I still face the same issues that you're finding yourself facing though.

For the most part, I don't even make an attempt to deploy things like Field-Level Security (FLS).

Instead, I just keep in mind that I need to (in the target org) update the page permissions for who can view the Visualforce pages I deploy, update the FLS for the fields I deploy, update profile settings for SObjects and RecordTypes that I deploy, etc...

There are issues with scaling this approach, and editing profiles for access to SObjects and RecordTypes is a big pain, but it should be manageable for small teams (say, 3 developers or less).